# Rails persisting data when using Devise/Chrome web driver/Capybara/FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, devise, factory-bot

I'm a relatively new Rails dev having an issue with testing my app. I am trying to test Devise sign up functionality, however, I am still getting persisting data. Here's the test code:

```
before(:all) do
 @state = FactoryGirl.create(:state)
 @brewery = FactoryGirl.create(:brewery, state_id: @state.id)
 @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
 @new_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end

after(:all) do
 @state.destroy!
 @brewery.destroy!
 @user.destroy!
 @new_user.destory!
end


scenario "A user can create an account on Beerica", js: true do

 user_count = User.count


 visit new_user_registration_path

 fill_in 'Username', with: @user.username
 fill_in 'Email', with:  @user.email
 fill_in 'Password', with: @user.password
 fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: @user.password

 click_button 'Sign up'

 expect(page).to have_content('Welcome! You have signed up successfully.')
 expect(User.count).to eq(user_count + 1)
end

scenario "A user can add a brewery to their list of visited breweries", js: true do
 new_user = @new_user
 login_as(new_user, scope: new_user, run_callbacks: false)
 visit state_brewery_path(@state, @brewery)
 click_on "I visited this brewery"

 expect(user.breweries).to eq(1)
end
```

I have transactional fixtures set to true, and because I'm running Selenium with a Chrome Web Driver, I had to use js: true. The before all block here is the only way I could get data to run through the browser, but I need to delete it afterwards. Despite all this, I believe Devise is the reason two Users are persisting in my test db after the test runs (causing uniqueness errors with email). Here's my factory which should be making new users:

```
factory :user do
 sequence(:username) {|n| "baconpancakes#{n}"}
 sequence(:email) {|n| "baconpancakes#{n}@example.com"}
 password "makinbaconpancakes"
 password_confirmation "makinbaconpancakes"
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also I'm aware DatabaseCleaner might help, but do I need it?

Answer (score 0):

`before(:all)` runs the block one time before all of the examples are run.

`before(:each)` runs the block one time before each of your specs in the file

`before(:all)` sets the instance variables @state, @brewery, @user, @new_user one time before all of the it blocks are run.

However, :before(:each) resets the instance variables in the before block every time an it block is run.

Same thing for `after(:all)`, so your test user does not get deleted.